# Why can't I add a fill layer to this plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

this plots a bar graph with the type of cut on the x-axis and the proportion of that cut within the dataset on the y-axis

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., group = 1))
```

This plots the same bar graph, but fills in the bars based on the color of diamond within that cut

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., group = 1, fill = color))
```

I see no difference between these two graphs.  Why does "fill = color" have no effect in the second line of code? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify `group = color`:

*edited to show proportions all on the same scale

```r
ggplot(diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cut, y = ..prop.., group = color, fill = color),
           position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: that's good to know.  in that case it looks like you just needed to specify `group=color`.  i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew! But it appears that the proportion on the y-axis is now based out of 3 - is there a way to correct that and return it to a normal 100% scale?

Comment: It's on a normal 100% scale - the stacked representation is the issue.  you can change it to grouped bars if you want to see all the proportions on the same scale.  see update

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm teaching myself R and this exercise came from the R for Data Science textbook and was driving me crazy! The steps to make this plot accurate go well beyond what's been covered so far, so I wonder if they know what they wrote!